# Entity framework filter on nested class

Tags: entity-framework, linq

My class is looks like this,

```
 public class Customer
 {
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
 }

 public class Shop
 {
  public string FacilityType { get; set; }
  public Certifications ShopCertifications { get; set; }
 }

 public class Certifications
 {
  public bool M1002 { get; set; }
  public bool M1003 { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a list of customer. For example, `List<Customer> Entity = IfetchedFromMyDataBase;` And it's lookes like this,

```
 Entity[0]:
 {{"id":1,"Name":"Basanta",
    Shops[0]:{{"FacilityType":"MOB","ShopCertifications":null}}
    Shops[1]:{{"FacilityType":"BLAH","ShopCertifications":
                              {{"M1002":true,"M1003":false}}}}
 }}
 Entity[1]://So on
```

Now I want to fetch data whose FacilityType = MOB. So the above data should return one Customer with one Shop. Because MOB is present in only one Shop.

I used `where`, `any` and `all`. Nothing worked. Even my bellow query not working to filter only FacilityType.

```
Var Data = Entity.Where(m => m.Shops.Any(n => n.FacilityType == "MOB")).ToList();
```

Not even my LINQ,

```
var data = (from d in Entity
            where (d.Shops.Any(x => x.FacilityType.ToUpper() == "MOB"))  
            select d);
```

When I query the above, both returning `Customer with all the Shops. I mean one Customer two Shops, even it's FacilityType == "BLAH"`. Strange!

I went through almost all the post related to this in SO. But no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = (from d in Entity
            where (d.Shops.Any(x => x.FacilityType.ToUpper() == "MOB"))  
            select d);
```

This will return you all Customers that contain a "MOB" facilityType. So if the customer contains a "MOB" and "BLAH" then that customer is returned. The Shops collection for that customer is not filtered to just the "MOB" shops.

If you want just the customers that have "MOB"s and their "MOB" shops..

```
var data = Entity
  .Where(d=> d.Shops.Any(x=> x.FacilityType.ToUpper() == "MOB"))
  .Select(x=> new { Facility = x, 
      MobShops = x.Shops
       .Where(s=> s.FacilityType.ToUpper() == "MOB")
       .ToList()})
  .ToList();
```

This will give you a data structure with the Facility and it's list of matching shops.

Alternatively if you're just interested in the Facility and then parsing it's specific type of shops, I'd consider adding a helper function to your Facility entity to provide the desired shop filtering:

I.e.

```
public IEnumerable<Shop> ShopsOfType(string shopType)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(shopType))
    return new List<Shop>(); // or null

  shopType = shopType.ToUpper();
  return Shops.Where(s=>s.FacilityType.ToUpper() == shopType).ToList();
}
```

Things to keep in mind here:
If your repository-like method that returned The Customers (Entity) returns a List/IEnumerable you either are dealing with eager loading all shops, or running into lazy-load scenarios. A pattern I promote is to have these methods return IQueryable so that consumers can filter the data prior to anything being executed on the DB. This way an ORM like EF can work out its Joins without explicit includes and you can select the appropriate data you want (I.e. to populate a view model, etc.) rather than fetching an entire object graph.

Consider making FacilityType a FK to a lookup table with a numeric Key column. This can be mapped to an enumeration in code or an Entity. This avoids the need to deal with potentially case-sensitive strings and improves performance /w indexing.

Comment: It's not working bro. Giving error the name select does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Please have a look on my updated question, and let me know if any luck.

Comment: There was a missing right parenthesis before the .Select(), it should be applied against the .Where() not the .Any()... In any case the behaviour you seek is not how Linq works. You are selecting on Customers so it will return any customer that matches your criteria. (and *all* associated data) It does not filter your associated entities unless you .Select() them separately.

Comment: Thanks. Now your query is working fine. **MobShops = x.Shops** It has filter data. But in **Facility = x**, It has all records. Is there any way to fetch the outer class with only have filter inner records ?

Comment: Not with the original entities. You can either use a method like the ShopsOfType() declared in your Facility class as in the above example, or if you want to do something like serialize/transfer an object then I'd look at using POCO view models / DTOs defined with the fields and relationships you want, then populate it from the entities.